# Issue with DataFrame na() fill methods and ambiguous reference

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I'm using Spark 1.3.1 where joining two dataframes repeats the column(s) being
joined.  I'm left outer joining two data frames and want to send the
resulting dataframe to the `na().fill()` method to convert nulls to known
values based on the data type of the column.  I've built a map of
"table.column" -> "value" and pass that to the fill method.  But I get
exception instead of success :(.  What are my options?  I see that there is a dataFrame.withColumnRenamed method but I can only rename one column.  I have joins that involve more than one column.  Do I just have to ensure that there is a unique set of column names, regardless of table aliases in the dataFrame where I apply the na().fill() method?

Given:

```scala
scala> val df1 = sqlContext.jsonFile("people.json").as("df1")
df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [first: string, last: string]

scala> val df2 = sqlContext.jsonFile("people.json").as("df2")
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [first: string, last: string]
```

I can join them together with

```scala
val df3 = df1.join(df2, df1("first") === df2("first"), "left_outer")
```

And I have a map that converts data type to value.

```scala
scala> val map = Map("df1.first"->"unknown", "df1.last" -> "unknown",
"df2.first" -> "unknown", "df2.last" -> "unknown")
```

But executing fill(map) results in exception.

```scala
scala> df3.na.fill(map)

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'first' is ambiguous,
could be: first#6, first#8.;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can replace only values by values, e.g. "Alberto" -> "unknown", "Bruce" -> "unknown", but not referring those values as positions in your `DataFrame`, here is where you should see [DataFrameNaFunctions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions), furthermore I don't know exactly what you want to do, if you want to replace values, or rename columns, could you be more specific?

Comment: I see my map doesn't need the df1 references, which might be causing the confusion.  After the join, I want to replace the nulls that might be present with "unknown" in df3.  the na.fill() method takes a map of column -> value pairs, def fill(valueMap: immutable.Map[String,Any]): DataFrame.  where the String field references the column name.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I came up with. In my original example, there is nothing interesting left in df2 after the join, so I changed this to be classical department / employee example.

department.json

```json
{"department": 2, "name":"accounting"}
{"department": 1, "name":"engineering"}
```

person.json

```json
{"department": 1, "first":"Bruce", "last": "szalwinski"}
```

And now I can join the dataframes, build the map, and replace nulls with unknowns.

```scala
scala> val df1 = sqlContext.jsonFile("department.json").as("df1")
df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [department: bigint, name: string]

scala> val df2 = sqlContext.jsonFile("people.json").as("df2")
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [department: bigint, first: string, last: string]

scala> val df3 = df1.join(df2, df1("department") === df2("department"), "left_outer")
df3: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [department: bigint, name: string, department: bigint, first: string, last: string]

scala> val map = Map("first" -> "unknown", "last" -> "unknown")
map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(first -> unknown, last -> unknown)

scala> val df4 = df3.select("df1.department", "df2.first", "df2.last").na.fill(map)
df4: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [department: bigint, first: string, last: string]

scala> df4.show()
+----------+-------+----------+
|department|  first|      last|
+----------+-------+----------+
|         2|unknown|   unknown|
|         1|  Bruce|szalwinski|
+----------+-------+----------+
```